# Webview JavaScript en android con impresora Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

estoy haciendo una app con un puente que al presionar el botón de HTMl Ejecute una función de Android nativa.

Quiero hacer 3 botones en html que ejecuten cada uno la función de escanear, imprimir y desconectar(Último código agregado MaiBluetooth.java)...

**El código siguiente funciona a la perfección:**

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Dialogo" onClick="dialogo("Eso está Caliente")" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function dialogo(message){
            Android.androidAlert(message);
        }
  </script>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://url.html");  
    }

    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void androidAlert(String message) {
            DialogBox dbx = new DialogBox();
            dbx.dialogBox(message, "I get it", "", mContext);
        }
    }
}
```

**DialogBox.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class DialogBox {
    public boolean dialogBox(String msg, String okButton, String cancelButton, final Context activity) {
        Dialog v = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
        if (okButton != "") {
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(okButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { /**/ }
            });
        }
        if (cancelButton != "") {
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(cancelButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { /**/ }
            });
        }
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Ahora bien, lo que quiero hacer ahora es hacer 3 botones en Javascript que Cada uno ejecute las siguientes funciones: Escanear, Imprimir y Desconectar, ya que lo tomé de ejemplo de esta página:** http://www.codeplayon.com/2019/05/bluetooth-thermal-receipt-printer-android-integration-printer/

**MainBluetooth.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainBluetooth extends Activity implements Runnable {
    protected static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    Button mScan, mPrint, mDisc;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private UUID applicationUUID = UUID
            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private ProgressDialog mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog;
    private BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Scan);
        mScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View mView) {
                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainBluetooth.this, "Message1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent,
                                REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    } else {
                        ListPairedDevices();
                        Intent connectIntent = new Intent(MainBluetooth.this,
                                DeviceListActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(connectIntent,
                                REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });



        mPrint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mPrint);
        mPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View mView) {
                Thread t = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            OutputStream os = mBluetoothSocket
                                    .getOutputStream();
                            String BILL = "";

                            BILL = "                   XXXX MART    \n"
                                    + "                   XX.AA.BB.CC.     \n " +
                                    "                 NO 25 ABC ABCDE    \n" +
                                    "                  XXXXX YYYYYY      \n" +
                                    "                   MMM 590019091      \n";
                            BILL = BILL
                                    + "-----------------------------------------------\n";


                            BILL = BILL + String.format("%1$-10s %2$10s %3$13s %4$10s", "Item", "Qty", "Rate", "Totel");
                            BILL = BILL + "\n";
                            BILL = BILL
                                    + "-----------------------------------------------";
                            BILL = BILL + "\n " + String.format("%1$-10s %2$10s %3$11s %4$10s", "item-001", "5", "10", "50.00");
                            BILL = BILL + "\n " + String.format("%1$-10s %2$10s %3$11s %4$10s", "item-002", "10", "5", "50.00");
                            BILL = BILL + "\n " + String.format("%1$-10s %2$10s %3$11s %4$10s", "item-003", "20", "10", "200.00");
                            BILL = BILL + "\n " + String.format("%1$-10s %2$10s %3$11s %4$10s", "item-004", "50", "10", "500.00");

                            BILL = BILL
                                    + "\n-----------------------------------------------";
                            BILL = BILL + "\n\n ";

                            BILL = BILL + "                   Total Qty:" + "      " + "85" + "\n";
                            BILL = BILL + "                   Total Value:" + "     " + "700.00" + "\n";

                            BILL = BILL
                                    + "-----------------------------------------------\n";
                            BILL = BILL + "\n\n ";
                            os.write(BILL.getBytes());
                            //This is printer specific code you can comment ==== > Start

                            // Setting height
                            int gs = 29;
                            os.write(intToByteArray(gs));
                            int h = 104;
                            os.write(intToByteArray(h));
                            int n = 162;
                            os.write(intToByteArray(n));

                            // Setting Width
                            int gs_width = 29;
                            os.write(intToByteArray(gs_width));
                            int w = 119;
                            os.write(intToByteArray(w));
                            int n_width = 2;
                            os.write(intToByteArray(n_width));


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("MainBluetooth", "Exe ", e);
                        }
                    }
                };
                t.start();
            }
        });

        mDisc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dis);
        mDisc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View mView) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter != null)
                    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            }
        });

    }// onCreate

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            if (mBluetoothSocket != null)
                mBluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Tag", "Exe ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            if (mBluetoothSocket != null)
                mBluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Tag", "Exe ", e);
        }
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int mRequestCode, int mResultCode,
                                 Intent mDataIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(mRequestCode, mResultCode, mDataIntent);

        switch (mRequestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
                if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle mExtra = mDataIntent.getExtras();
                    String mDeviceAddress = mExtra.getString("DeviceAddress");
                    Log.v(TAG, "Coming incoming address " + mDeviceAddress);
                    mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter
                            .getRemoteDevice(mDeviceAddress);
                    mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                            "Connecting...", mBluetoothDevice.getName() + " : "
                                    + mBluetoothDevice.getAddress(), true, false);
                    Thread mBlutoothConnectThread = new Thread(this);
                    mBlutoothConnectThread.start();
                    // pairToDevice(mBluetoothDevice); This method is replaced by
                    // progress dialog with thread
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    ListPairedDevices();
                    Intent connectIntent = new Intent(MainBluetooth.this,
                            DeviceListActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainBluetooth.this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ListPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
                .getBondedDevices();
        if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) {
                Log.v(TAG, "PairedDevices: " + mDevice.getName() + "  "
                        + mDevice.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice
                    .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            mBluetoothSocket.connect();
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        } catch (IOException eConnectException) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", eConnectException);
            closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void closeSocket(BluetoothSocket nOpenSocket) {
        try {
            nOpenSocket.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "SocketClosed");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotCloseSocket");
        }
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainBluetooth.this, "DeviceConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public static byte intToByteArray(int value) {
        byte[] b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();

        for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
            System.out.println("Selva  [" + k + "] = " + "0x"
                    + UnicodeFormatter.byteToHex(b[k]));
        }

        return b[3];
    }

    public byte[] sel(int val) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
        buffer.putInt(val);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer.array();
    }

    public void mScan(String viewById) {
    }
}
```

para más detalle pueden revisar el código de la aplicación de bluetooth en esta página:
http://www.codeplayon.com/2019/05/bluetooth-thermal-receipt-printer-android-integration-printer/

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que tienes?

Comment: Hay que mencionar cual es el problema que se tiene para resolver la tarea, no es correcto preguntar para que alguién resuelva lo que falta, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.